# Having trouble with making unusual shaped hover on first and last child

Tags: html, css

Check out the JSfiddle showing what I am up to: http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/FPj3s/1/

HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">BLAH</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MORE <br /> BLAH</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">STILL <br /> MORE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">YADDA <br /> YADDA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ETC ETC <br /> ETC ETC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FINISH</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;}
}
#navigation {
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 25px;
}

#navigation li {
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 94px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: lightgrey;
}

#navigation li:first-child {
    border-top: 40px solid lightgrey;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 70px;
    background: none;
}

#navigation li:first-child a {
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    right: 0px
}

#navigation li:last-child {
    border-top: 40px solid lightgrey;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 70px;
    background: none;
}

#navigation li:last-child a {
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    left: 5px;
}
#navigation li:last-child a:hover {
    top: -35px;
    left: 5px;
}

#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    background: grey;
}
```

The lightgrey shapes are what I would like the hover to look like. Only the first and last children need to look different but I am unsure of how to go about messing with the borders on hover without ruining the layout. I have had to move the first and last 'a' elements because of the border shenanigans and now I'm stuck.
What would you suggest?

---

EDIT:
I just realised I could do this to change the shape of the hover bit but the link position is still causing trouble

```
#navigation li:last-child a:hover {
    border-top: 40px solid grey;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 70px;
    background: none;
}
```

[See it live here on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/SbTqq/)

Comment: Boy did those shapes on the original fiddle look bad on my Safari browser. :/ @koala_dev's fiddle worked great to fix it on my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties you want to change are of the `<li>` elements so target the list items hover state and change the background and border color

```
#navigation li:hover {
    background: grey;
}

#navigation li:first-child:hover,
#navigation li:last-child:hover{
    background: none;
    border-top-color: grey;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPj3s/4/)**

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I had tried li:last-child:hover but must have done something wrong because it didn't do anything. Thansk for the help!

Comment: @Ampersand No problem, don't forget to mark the best answer as "accepted" to let the community know your issue has been solved

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you want to set the 'border-top' to grey for the first/ last child.

You could use in CSS:

```
#navigation li:first-child:hover {
border-top: 40px solid lightgrey;
}
```

But this didn't work in Google Chrome, for me, so perhaps just apply that as a hover effect using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this as well and had it not work but another user changed li a:hover to li:hover in another rule and that was what caused the problem

Comment: @Ampersand it should be `li:hover`

Comment: I should have said that changing it to li:hover was what fixed the problem.